# How to delete particular elements in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

> I have an array with multiple objects.How can i delete an element in a
>   object.
>
> For example i have attached a image in that i need to delete
>   organization element.
>
> Please help me out to fix.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are not going to just hand over the solution for you. That is not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: What do you mean by deleting? You dont want only that field from your json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = {name: 'pardeep', 'sirname': 'jain'}
delete a['name']
console.log(a);
```

Just use `delete` keyword for the key like this -

```
delete objectName['keyName']
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

```js
const deleteAttribute = (array, attribute) => array.map(x => {
  // Delete the attribute here
  delete x[attribute];
  return x;
});

const arr = [{
  attr: 'hello',
  color: 'red',
  organization: 'Good'
}, {
  attr: 'world',
  color: 'blue',
  organization: 'bad'
}];

console.log(deleteAttribute(arr, 'organization'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `delete` like below

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'hi',
  test: 'x',
  organization: 'X'
}, {
  name: 'guys',
  test: 'y',
  organization: 'Y'
}];

  console.log(arr.map(x => { delete x.organization; return x}));
```

Comment: Come on man, don't copy/paste my stuff. That's not cool

Comment: @molamk Sorry. My intention was only to help him. I was mocking some array but meanwhile got yours. So, I took the array from  you. I ll change it

Comment: It's alright no worries